# How to set timers differently for each pictures in the slider?

Tags: php, jquery, css

I am implementing a page on which when page loads, the slideshow starts. The pictures for that slideshows are coming form back-end(database). Each picture has its own timer as there are some pictures with the content while some with only heading or logos. At present, I have the same time interval set to each pictures, but now I want to set the time intervals according to their values in database.

here is the code that I have for now with the same time interval:

**index.php**

```
<section class='images'>
    <? foreach($model->slides as $slide){ ?>
        <div class='image'>
            <img class='image' src="<?= $slide->image ?.'/pictures/'.$slides->image : '' ?>">
        </div>
    <? } ?>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.images').slick({
            slidesToShow: 1,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplaySpeed: 10000,
      });
    });
</script>
```

In **indexController.php**(Controller)

```
public function index(Array $params = []){
    $this->view->slides = \Model\Slide_Picture::getList(['orderBy'=>"image_order asc"]);
    $this->loadView($this->view);
}
```

`My table 'slide_images' consist of 3 fields: image, image_order and timer`.

As mentioned earlier, this code helps me to get the image slideshow with the time interval of 10s, but now I want to set it different for each images. Say for example, there are 3 images in the database, Picture 1 has a timer value 30s, picture 2 has that of 10s, and picture 3 has value of 40s. So is this possible? If yes, how can I achieve it. Thanks in advance. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to add your timing to the database for each image, then once you do that you can return the timing value, and use it in a data attribute. (seems you have done that `timer`)

Then utilise the `afterChange` event to get the value and then dynamically change the `autoplaySpeed` speed.

Below is an example, you would need to integrate it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var images = $('.images');

  images.slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 1000,
  }).on("afterChange", function(e, slick) {
    var slideTime = $('div[data-slick-index="' + slick.currentSlide + '"]').data("timer");
    images.slick("setOption", "autoplaySpeed", slideTime);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>

<section class='images'>
  <div class='image' data-timer="2000">
    <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class='image' data-timer="100">
    <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class='image' data-timer="1000">
    <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class='image' data-timer="3000">
    <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
  <div class='image' data-timer="1000">
    <img class='image' src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
  </div>
</section>
```

Run the snippet to see it in action.

---

So your loop would look something like:

```
<section class="images">
<?php foreach ($model->slides as $slide): ?>
    <div class="image"<?= !empty($slide->timer) ? ' data-timer="'.$slide->timer.'"' : null ?>>
        <img class="image" src="<?= $slide->image ? '/pictures/'.$slides->image : null ?>">
    </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
</section>
```